# Can't set up a proper ajax call using struts2 and ajax

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, jsp, struts2

I've been trying to get this code to work. THe basic idea is I want to create an ajax request when the textbox whose id is "user" to go back to the server (apache) via an ajax call.

The error I get is a 404 when doing a `http://localhost:8080/CheckUserAvailabilityAction.do?username=ds` request.

This is my code.
Struts2 class CheckUserAvailabilityAction.java:

```
public class CheckUserAvailabilityAction extends ActionSupport implements
    ServletRequestAware {

//struts action
public String execute() {

    String output = "success";
    /*
        SOME CODE
    */  
    return output;

}
}
```

Here's my jsp:

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>

<%@ taglib uri="http://jakarta.apache.org/struts/tags-bean"
    prefix="bean"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://jakarta.apache.org/struts/tags-html"
    prefix="html"%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<script src="js/scripts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>

<script>
    var url = "HelloWorld.jsp";
    function makeRequest(url) {
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else if (window.ActiveXObject) { // IE
            try {
                httpRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
            }
            catch (e) {
                try {
                    httpRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                }
                catch (e) {             }
            }
        }

        if (!httpRequest) {
            return false;

        }

        httpRequest.onreadystatechange = alertContents();
        httpRequest.open('GET', url);
        httpRequest.send();

        //Redirecting to the HelloUser.jsp
        window.location.replace(url);

    }
    function alertContents() {

        if (httpRequest.readyState === 4) {

            if (httpRequest.status === 200) {

                alert(httpRequest.responseText);

            } else {

                alert('There was a problem with the request.');

            }

        }

    }
    $(function(){
        $("#username").blur("/CheckUserAvailability");
    });

    function checkUserAvailability(){
        var name = $("#username").val();

        $.get(
                "/CheckUserAvailabilityAction.do", 
                { 'username': name },
                function () {
                    var response = $(data).find("response").text();
                     $("#response").hide();
                     $("#response").empty();
                     $("#response").append(response);
                     $("#response").show("slow");               
                } 
        );
    }





</script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>New user - Registration form</title>
</head>
<body id="bodyStyling">
    <%
        if ("noSexSelected".equalsIgnoreCase(request
                .getParameter("register"))) {
    %>
    <div id="registrationFailure">
        <h4>Please select a Sex</h4>
    </div>
    <%
        }
    %>
    <form name="myForm" action="checkUserNameAvailability" method="post">
        <!-- onsubmit="return validateForm(this);" -->
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><h2 id="IntroductionReg">New User Registration</h2></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="myTableDataStyling">Name:</td>
                <td><input name="username" id="username" type="text"
                 onblur="checkUserAvailability()" /></td>
                <td><label id="usrLabel"></label></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="myTableDataStyling">Password:</td>
                <td><input name="password" type="password" onclick= /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="myTableDataStyling">Confirm password:</td>
                <td><input name="passwordConfirmation" type="password"
                    onclick="this.value''" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="myTableDataStyling">Age:</td>
                <td><input name="age" onclick="this.value=''" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="myTableDataStyling">Sex:</td>
                <td><select name="sex">
                        <option value="">- Select -</option>
                        <option value="M">M</option>
                        <option value="F">F</option>

                </select>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="myTableDataStyling">Address:</td>
                <td><input name="address" onclick="this.value=''" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="myTableDataStyling">E-mail:</td>
                <td><input name="email" onclick="this.value=''" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <input type="submit" value="Register user" />
    </form>
    <div id="outputDiv"></div>
<div id="response"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my struts.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
    "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
    "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">
<struts>

    <!-- Here, I declare the actions for the com.tcs.controller package classes -->
    <package name="damo" extends="struts-default">
        <action name="process" class="com.tcs.controller.User">
            <result name="success">/process.jsp</result>
        </action>


        <action name="login" class="com.tcs.action.LoginAction">
            <result name="success">HelloUser.jsp</result>
            <result name="error">Login.jsp</result>
        </action>

        <action name="register" class="com.tcs.action.RegisterUserAction">
            <result name="success">process.jsp</result>
            <result name="error">process.jsp</result>
        </action>

        <action name="checkUserNameAvailability" class="com.tcs.action.CheckUserAvailabilityAction">
            <result name="success" type='redirect'>register.action</result>
            <result name="error">process.jsp</result>
        </action>



    </package>






</struts>
```

I'm struggling to get my checkUserAvailability function to make a valid request, I'm lost since I have minimal knowledge of struts.

Help is greatly appreciated

Thanks.

Comment: Use `<s:url>` to create url-s.

Comment: What are `web.xml, struts.xml`? Struts2 action requires mapping to the url specified, and when deployed it should start at the specified webapp context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer the below url for exact solution.

[Send json data to struts 2 ajax](http://tech.learnerandtutor.com/send-json-object-to-struts-2-action-by-jquery-ajax/)

[Dynamic Drop Down List](http://tech.learnerandtutor.com/dynamic-drop-down-list-with-struts-2-and-ajax/)

Comment: Thanks for the links. I've realised my knowledge of struts is not quite there yet and I'm going to go back to the documentation.

Thanks.

Comment: If this is ok, just make the answer up/right. For Others it will be useful.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing your project name from the url. Could you test

```
http://localhost:8080/[yourProjectName]/CheckUserAvailabilityAction.do?username=ds
```

so that if your project in your workspace is called `foo` you'd call url

```
http://localhost:8080/foo/CheckUserAvailabilityAction.do?username=ds
```

Comment: @afsalparangooz - It didn't work. But thanks anyway!